# Grouping in t-sql with latest dates

Tags: t-sql, grouping

I have a table like this

```
Event ID | Contract ID | Event date | Amount |
----------------------------------------------
1        | 1           | 2009-01-01 |    100 |
2        | 1           | 2009-01-02 |     20 |
3        | 1           | 2009-01-03 |     50 |
4        | 2           | 2009-01-01 |     80 |
5        | 2           | 2009-01-04 |     30 |
```

For each contract I need to fetch the latest event and amount associated with the event and get something like this

```
Event ID | Contract ID | Event date | Amount |
----------------------------------------------
3        | 1           | 2009-01-03 |     50 |
5        | 2           | 2009-01-04 |     30 |
```

I can't figure out how to group the data correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL 2k5/2k8:

```
with cte_ranked as (
 select *
    , row_number() over (
         partition by ContractId order by EvantDate desc) as [rank]
    from [table])
select * 
   from cte_ranked
   where [rank] = 1;
```

SQL 2k:

```
 select t.*
    from table as t
    join (
        select max(EventDate) as MaxDate
            , ContractId 
            from table 
            group by ContractId) as mt
       on t.ContractId = mt.ContractId
          and t.EventDate = mt.MaxDate
```